# Upload Image and Display on Separate Page Using PHP

Tags: php, html, image

I'm stuck trying to get an uploaded image to display from an HTML form onto a PHP page.

All I want to do is have the image display on the second page.

Page One Code (HTML Form)

```
<form action="ShowReunionPhoto.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" />
    Description <input type="text" name="description" />
    Upload Photo: <input type="file" name="reunionPhoto" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload Photo" />
</form>
```

Page Two (PHP)

```
<?php
    $Name = $_POST['name'];
    $Description = $_POST['description'];
    $Reunion = fopen("Reunion.txt", "ab"); {
    fwrite($Reunion, $Name . "\n" . $Description . "\n");
    fclose($Reunion);
    }

    $ReunionImage = $_FILES["file"]["reunionPhoto"];

    echo '<img src="' . $ReunionImage . '">';

    echo "<pre>\n";
    echo readfile("Reunion.txt");
    echo "</pre>\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make your image accessible, it needs to be copied to your project's directory.

Let's say you want to copy it to the `images` directory, relative to the script. Make sure your `images` directory exists.

```php
$uploadedFile = $_FILES['reunionPhoto'];
$sourcePath = $uploadedFile['tmp_name'];
$destinationFileName = $uploadedFile['name'];
$destinationPath = __DIR__ . '/images/' . $destinationFileName;

move_uploaded_file($sourcePath, $destinationPath);
```

Then, in your `<img>` you can display that image.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. One question I have is if I need to upload different images how do I alter the code so I don't have the single image hard-coded in there. I'm referring to the code after __DIR__. Or would I use photo.jpg for that as well? Also, I'm uploading the image to the root directory of where my PHP file is located. Thanks again.

Comment: I updated my answer to allow you to keep the original filename. If you want the image to be in the root, just remove the `/images` part, however it's always nice to have images in a directory.

Comment: Just a warning, if you want it to upload to the root, without additional checking if a file already exists of has a specific extension, someone can overwrite your PHP script by uploading files named for example `index.php`! And this is *very* bad :)

Answer (score 0):

you can even use the [phpUpload](https://github.com/fabriziomanca/phpUpload) library

```
$pUp = new phpUpload($_FILES['file']);
$pUp->maxSize('10');
$pUp->allowedType(["image/jpeg"]);
$pUp->newName("New_name");

if($pUp->run("test", true)){
    echo "<img src='test/$pUp->output' />";
}
```